# what are the conditions to be a true array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Javascript do not have true array. because when i tested out this thing in google console i was surprised to see that there is no difference between an object and an array.

```
var obj = {};
var arr = [];

typeof obj; //object
typeof arr; //object
```

i am curious to know

> why this is so?

and

> Do really javascript possess false array?

and

> Is this `typeof` is wrong , i mean do this not differentiate between object and an array?

and

> what are the conditions to be a true array?

thanks!

Comment: there are 5 primitive types : null undefined number string boolean, all others are just objects. if you want the true type do this : `({}).toString.apply([])`

Comment: What do you mean by a "real array"? `Array` is a type of `Object` who properties and behaviors are specified in [ECMAScript 15.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4).

Comment: `[] instanceof Array; //true` but i'm pretty sure it is not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is a dynamic language and its objects are very flexible. And there is really no gurantee that, an object you have is of particular type. Because we can do [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

If you want to know if an object is an Array or not, you can use this

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == '[object Array]';
```

This is taken from the underscore.js library's `_.isArray` function. Since it is popular and widely used, this method should be reliable.

If your environment supports ECMA 5.1, then you can also use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) function, like this

```
Array.isArray(obj);
```

Comment: There is also native `Array.isArray`.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks :) I updated my answer with that.